# How can I find vector $w$ that his projection about $span(v)$ is $7v$ and his projection about $span(u)$ is $-8u$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, projection-matrices

given these vectors:
$$
    v=\begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\
    -4 \\
    2  \\
    \end{pmatrix} , u = \begin{pmatrix}
    -4 \\
    1 \\
    3  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

How can I find vector $w$ that his projection about $span(v)$ is $7v$ and his projection about $span(u)$ is $-8u$ ?

I don't have idea how to do it and I will be happy for help or hints for how to do it.

Comment: Which vector is $v$ and which one is $u$? You have a typo on one of them.

Comment: I am sorry, I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  the [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) of $\,w\,$ onto $\,\operatorname{span}(u)\,$ is $\,\dfrac{w \cdot u}{|u|^2}\,u = -8u\,$, so $\,w \cdot u = -8 |u|^2\,$, and similarly $\,w \cdot v = 7 |v|^2\,$.

Let $\;n=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}\,$, then it's easily verified that $n \cdot u = n \cdot v = 0\,$, so $\,\operatorname{span}(u,v,n)=\mathbb{R}^3\,$. Then let $\,w = \lambda u + \mu v + \nu n\,$ and solve the given conditions for $\,\lambda,\mu\,$:

$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
-8 |u|^2 = w \cdot u &= \lambda |u|^2 + \mu \,(u \cdot v) + \bcancel{\nu \, (n \cdot u)} \\
7 |v|^2 = w \cdot v &= \lambda \,(u \cdot v) + \mu |v|^2 + \bcancel{\nu \, (n \cdot v)}
\end{align}
$$

Note that $\,\nu\,$ remains undetermined, since the component orthogonal to $\,\operatorname{span}(u,v)\,$ does not affect the projections onto $\operatorname{span}(u)\,$ and $\,\operatorname{span}(v)$.